# TFS Build Destroy for 2013 to 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfsbuild

I need to destroy a build since deleting a build is not enough and I would like to use [TFS Build Destroy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-364138.TFSBuildDestroy). Unfortunately I cannot find it in 2015 since it only works with 2013 upon checking..

Is there a way to make it work for 2015? I'm trying not to resort to TFSBuild commands.

Comment: The 2 possible answers are: 1) use TFSBuild.exe from the command line, 2) we find you another extension. #2 is not a question fit for SO, and would be closed as off-topic. (Bonus answer would be to build your own extension).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as Dave said, if you don't want to resort to the TFSBuild commands, you have to build your own extension.

You can reference the source code of **TFS Build Destroy** extension, try to modify/debug then build your own extension. Please refer to below link to get the source code:
https://tfsbuilddestroy.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest